# Error while creating app using command prompt

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm, npx

I have installed nodejs and checked nodejs, npm and npx versions. All seems great and executed `npm install -g create-react-app` and it also got executed correctly. But after writing `create-react-app myapp` it is showing this error on command prompt.

```
Creating a new React app in `C:\Users\Dell\Documents\Javascript Tutorial && Summer training\reactjs course\todolist`

Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts...

events.js:352
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: spawn C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe ENOENT
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:269:19)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:467:16)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:82:21)
Emitted 'error' event on ChildProcess instance at:
    at ChildProcess.cp.emit (C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\create-react-app\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:34:29)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:275:12)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:467:16)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:82:21) {
  errno: -4058,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'spawn C:\\Windows\\system32\\cmd.exe',
  path: 'C:\\Windows\\system32\\cmd.exe',
  spawnargs: [
    '/d',
    '/s',
    '/c',
    '"npm ^"install^" ^"--save^" ^"--save-exact^" ^"--loglevel^" ^"error^" ^"react^" ^"react-dom^" ^"react-scripts@0.9.x^""'
  ]
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is not the correct way to initialize a react Application, as it's the incorrect use of `npx`.

Try uninstalling globally `create-react-app`

```
$ npm uninstall -g create-react-app
```

and then initializing your app

```
$ npx create-react-app myapp
```

Comment: By adding $ , it is showing that "'$' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.", now what to do

Comment: $ is just an indication that it is a shell command, don't include it